# Input Group like Bootstrap but without Flex?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create a Input Group from scratch like Bootstrap, I don't want to use Flex, So What is the best way to create a Input Group? I think older versions of Bootstrap have used `display: table` but I have heard it's not the best way because in some browsers like Safari works in another way ...

For example :

```
<div class="iptGroup">
    <span>@</span>
    <input type="text"></input>
</div>
```

I had this code and used `display: table` but neither worked in `-webkit-` browsers (some problems in width of `span`) or worked in Firefox ...

Any answer is appreciated ...

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: @ZimSystem I put that ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see nothing bad in using `display: table;` and `table-cell` in order to recreate input :

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font: 16px/1.4 sans-serif; }


input,
textarea {
  font: inherit;
}

.input-group {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group > * {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input-group-icon {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #777;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.input-group-area {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group input {
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<label class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-icon">@</div>
  <div class="input-group-area"><input type="text" placeholder="Email Address"></div>
</label>

<label class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-icon">Income:</div>
  <div class="input-group-area"><input type="text" value="0.00"></div>
  <div class="input-group-icon">$</div>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should use `div` to have better display with `display:table` or I can use `span` and `input` like my code above?

Comment: I asked that because I tried your code for `div` parent and some `button`s like a child and Cope/Paste your code and modified that and not worked ...

Comment: How would I display an image instead of the @ or $ ??

Comment: @developer12 don't use *images* (like `<img>`), use icon fonts. [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select/font)